# Customization of shared code base

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0

Every website (e.g. Stack Overflow, Server Fault) of the Stack Exchange network has the same code base (cf. [Does StackExchange 2.0 Share the Same CodeBase with SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55725)), but also has unique features like a custom theme and data (e.g. questions, users).

How do you manage this?

Is it a single instance that responds to multiple domains (**multi-tenant**)?

Or do you have **multiple instances** with different configurations?

If so, **how do you tell the code base which instance should be run?** Environment variables? Symlinks to custom code?

Same question for the database: do you have separate databases or one large database?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199141/163863 will answer some/most/all of your questions. They have a separate database for each site; which is hidden [in the answer by Marc](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199161/163863); I therefore think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Matt! It answers my questions, and I'm surprised because I thought it was multi-instance. I couldn't find it because I didn't know the term "multi-tenant" (now I've updated the question with this term).